# Best Practices on UI Architectures

Tags: gui-design

<strike>I wanted know some of the recommended best practices for UI Architectures.</strike>

Also  How important is to understand browser architecture and web server architecture from UX point of view.

Comment: Please provide more information or ask a more specific question. What do you mean by UI Architectures?

Comment: There are two questions here, the first is probably too vague to lead to a productive answer (though maybe much debate). The second question could use more context, and might be best handled entirely separate.

Answer (score 1):

The classic UI book in this field (web applications) is "Dont make me Think" by Steve Krug.
Highly recommended.

The user should NOT have to understand browser and web server architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the internals of web clients / servers / protocols etc. can be both good and bad as it can give a UX designer new ideas but can also induce premature limitations. Limitations that continue to pose restrictions for further work.

You can argue that if your strategy is to *design what the user wants*, you should start with the solution and then work your way back to the technology. Thus, deeper technical knowledge is not relevant (more technical minded people can help you out here.)

(Possibly related: *[Video: Steve Jobs Insult Response](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FF-tKLISfPE)* )